# Vue 3 props are not passed to the child element

Tags: vuejs3, vue-props

I'm trying to pass an object to a child element as a prop, but I get an arr[0] val instead of `{ id: 1, name: 'General' }`.

There I bind prop value, `currentRoom` is a const with Object.

```html
<input-message :currentRoom="currentRoom"/>
```

`currentRoom`s value is correct there and equals `{id: 1, name: 'General'}`.

In child element I try to get props that way:

```js
const props = defineProps({
  currentRoom: Object
});
```

The whole code:

**container.vue**

```html
<template>
    <AppLayout title="Dashboard">
        <template #header>
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                Chat
            </h2>
        </template>

        <div class="py-12">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
                    <message-container :room="currentRoom"/>
                    <input-message :currentRoom="currentRoom" :customText="'blablabla'"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </AppLayout>
</template>

<script setup>
import AppLayout from '../../Layouts/AppLayout.vue';
import MessageContainer from "./messageContainer.vue";
import InputMessage from "./inputMessage.vue";
import {defineComponent} from "vue";

defineComponent([
    AppLayout,
    MessageContainer,
    InputMessage
])

let chatRooms = [];
let currentRoom = [];
let messages = [];

const getRooms = () => {
    axios.get('/chat/rooms')
    .then( response => {
        chatRooms = response.data;
        setRoom(response.data[0]);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}

const setRoom = (room) => {
    currentRoom = room;
    // If I console.log currentRoom here, it is displayed correctly!
    console.log(currentRoom)
    getMessages();
}

const getMessages = () => {
    axios.get('/chat/rooms/' + currentRoom.id + '/messages')
    .then(response => {
        messages = response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

getRooms();
</script>
```

**inputMessage.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div class="relative h-10 m-1">
        <div style="border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;" class="grid grid-cols-6">
            <input
                type="text"
                v-model="message"
                @keyup.enter="sendMessage"
                placeholder="Say something..."
                class="col-span-5 outline-none p-1"
            />
            <button
                @click="sendMessage"
                class="place-self-end bg-gray-500 hover:bg-blue-700 p-1 mt-1 rounded text-white">
                Send
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    currentRoom: Object
    // customText: Text
});

console.log(props.currentRoom);
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the `props` with `console.log(props)` ?

Comment: where is `init` called? maybe the component is not mounted yet.

Comment: @IVOGELOV yes, its empy also

Comment: @Orbis i have tried with mouned(), result is the same. BUT i noticed, that if i add, for example, console.log(currentRoom), it magically appears. but after refreshing the page still void. Even i remove console.log() my variable content appears in dev tools, looks so strange.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just do it right way and it will work.

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const MyComponent = {
  props: {
    currentRoom : {
      type: Object,
      default: {}
    }
  },  
  setup(props) {
    console.log(`props.currentRoom: ${JSON.stringify(props.currentRoom)}`)
  },
  template: `<div class="MyComponent">currentRoom: {{JSON.stringify(currentRoom)}}</div>`   
}

const App = {
  components: {
    MyComponent
  },
  setup() {  
    const rooms = ref([]);   
    const addRoom = () => { rooms.value.push( {id: rooms.value.length + 1, name: 'General'} ); }    
    return { rooms, addRoom }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
.MyComponent {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">  
  App.rooms: {{rooms}}<hr/>
    rooms[0]: <my-component :current-room="rooms[0]"></my-component>
    rooms: <my-component v-for="room in rooms" :current-room="room"></my-component>
  <button type="button" @click="addRoom()">Add Room</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i used 

const rooms = ref([]);   
const addRoom = () => { rooms.value.push( {id: rooms.value.length + 1, name: 'General'});

and magically it works!

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

You `currentRoom` data property is not reactive. So, I guess, it triggers no updates to the props. You should define it this way:

```
const currentRoom = reactive({});
```

or

```
const currentRoom = ref({});
```

In case of `ref()` you have then change the `value` of the `ref` like this

```
currentRoom.value = room;
```

Hope it helps.

---

Your `currentRoom` is an Array. That's why you get `[]` in the console, when your array is empty.

Check your axios request if you get any data at all. (Browser DevTools Network Tab)

Generally, you should pass one room item to your `currentRoom` prop or threat your prop as array.

Like this:

```
<table border=1>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(room, index)  in props.currentRoom">
       <td>{{index}}</td>
       <td>{{room.id}}</td>
       <td>{{room.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

Here is a working [playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: No, it is not an array, in getRooms func i call the setRoom(response.data[0]), where response.data[0] is an object, i checked it for sure. The problem is that i get nothing, even if it displayed as an empty array, when im trying to get currentRoom.id i get message, that currentRoom is undefined, not even an array. Thank for your try btw!

Comment: @VadimGerich i have to agree that current room is initially an array: `let currentRoom = [];` can you change it to undefined?

Comment: @Orbis in this case i get undefined in children el (this is important given the following
 ). ALSO i noticed, that if i try to {{currentRoom}} in parent el`s template, even before including the child one, it print also '[]'. this variable is not reactive (i dont know why, maybe it is the specific of axios, as i have said - im a newbee). do you know why is it possible?

Comment: How about now, you see your second answer here?

Comment: @Mises it helped, did not see it before you have commended.